# Mocking Spring Data Repository

Tags: junit, spring-data, mockito

I have a `BeerRepository` interface that extends `JPARepository<Beer,UUID>`. This interface contains this method.

```
Page<Beer> findAllByBeerName(String beerName, Pageable pageable);
```

In a controller handler method, I have this.

```
  Page<Beer> pagedResult = beerRepository.findAllByBeerName(beer.getBeerName(), 
    createPageRequest(0,10,Sort.Direction.DESC,"beerName"));
```

I am trying to unit test the controller handler method.

The `@BeforeEach` method is this.

```
    . . .
    Page<Beer> pagedResponse;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    beerList = new ArrayList<Beer>();
    beerList.add(Beer.builder().build());
    beerList.add(Beer.builder().build());
    pagedResponse = new PageImpl(beerList);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(controller)
            .build();
}
```

My @Test method is this.

```
@Test
void processFindFormReturnMany() throws Exception{

    when(beerRepository.findAllByBeerName(anyString(), PageRequest.of(0,
          10,Sort.Direction.DESC,"beerName"))).thenReturn(pagedResponse);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/beers"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("beers/beerList"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("selections", hasSize(2)));
}
```

On running the test, I'm getting

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at 
guru.sfg.brewery.web.controllers.BeerControllerTest.
processFindFormReturnMany
(BeerControllerTest.java:67)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
 When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you cannot mix Mockito matchers with real values while mocking with `when(...)`. See [docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers).

In your case the following should work correctly:

```
when(beerRepository.findAllByBeerName(anyString(), eq(PageRequest.of(0,
          10,Sort.Direction.DESC,"beerName")))).thenReturn(pagedResponse);
```

or

```
when(beerRepository.findAllByBeerName(anyString(), any(PageRequest.class)).thenReturn(pagedResponse);
```

Finally, you can use the real expected string instead of `anyString()` and leave `PageRequest.of(...)` as is. It should work too (assuming that they were configured correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set mock class for param when you mock any method

```
when(beerRepository.findAllByBeerName(anyString(), any(Pageable.class)).thenReturn(pagedResponse);
```